# Highlighting keywords on page running into infinite loop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, highlighting

I am writing a test chrome extension in which I try to highlight all keywords on the current page. Unfortunately, I think I have a small gap in my logic, as it runs into an infinite loop. Specifically, after finding the first keyword match (assume the regex matches the word 'highlight'), it inserts the node, and then pulls and inserts the same 'highlight' textnode over and over again. The relevant code is as follows:

```
// Get all elements on the page   
const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < elements[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
    // Loop through each node
    let currNode = elements[i].childNodes[j];
    // Check for textnode
    if (currNode.nodeType === 3) {
      // Get first/next match
      for (let match; match = regex.exec(currNode.nodeValue); ) {
        // Create highlighted element
        let hlElement = document.createElement('span');
        hlElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(match[0]));
        hlElement.className = 'highlight';

        // Split current textnode at match and insert higlighted match in between
        let nextNode = currNode.splitText(match.index);
        nextNode.nodeValue = nextNode.nodeValue.substring(match[0].length);
        currNode.parentNode.insertBefore(hlElement, nextNode);
        currNode = nextNode;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to create a JSFiddle to replicate the behavior? At first glance I'd check the syntax of `for (let match; match = regex.exec(currNode.nodeValue); )` - I think you may want a while loop.

Comment: You should iterate from the last node to first. You should collect regexp matching results in an array and then iterate it in reverse.